# How to check whether my ISP is throttling my torrent/streaming speed?

Tags: video, streaming, bittorrent, throttling

I have exactly the same problem as [this one](https://superuser.com/q/116257/522), but unfortunately no helpful answer was provided, and the OP accepted a non-answer! So I guess I should ask again, here.

Recently I am having streaming issues with my Netflix and Amazon Prime Instant Videos. Youtube videos, on the other hand, work just fine. I did ping tests at [speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net), and the tests were just normal.

I wonder whether is my ISP throttling the speed of HD video streaming? Is there any website that allows me to check this?

Comment: You have have a look at an online service called Glasnost, which can help you test ISP throttling: http://broadband.mpi-sws.org/transparency/bttest.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that your ISP is throttling certain types of traffic.  If you have access to a VPN service (e.g. Private Internet Access, PureVPN, etc.), try connecting to Youtube or Netflix through the VPN tunnel.  The traffic between your machine and the VPN server will be encrypted and will look like noise to your ISP, so if they are throttling based on packet type, the VPN traffic should avoid the throttle.  Once you have established the VPN tunnel, try out the Youtube video again.  If it is going faster than it had been without the VPN tunnel, then your ISP may indeed be throttling your traffic.